# Netstream seekToNavCuePoint

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, netstream, netconnection

Found this code working properly with `FlvPlayback`. I have stored cuepoints within flv files. it works perfectly.

```
bkbut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,movie1);
function movie1(evt:MouseEvent):void{
rmys01.seekToNavCuePoint("chap01"); 
}
```

How should i call the same cuepoint using `NetStream` & `NetConnection`

i have loaded the same flv file using the below code

```
var ncConnection:NetConnection;
var nsStream:NetStream;
var strSource:String = "rhym01.flv";
nsStream = new NetStream(ncConnection);
nsStream.play(strSource);
vidDisplay.attachNetStream(nsStream);
```

On click of the button (bkbut), the "rhym01.flv" will start playing cuepoint named "chap01"

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for cue points on the NetStream. You can use just `seek` method instead.

I've seen people trying to get the meta data of the video and this way getting the cue points. If they are properly passed, you can later on seek to specific point of the video. Something like doing cue points by yourself.

Try checking the `cuePoints` property of the meta data callback.

Other than that - I don't think there is any other option.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution i have found is

```
nsStream.seek(15);
```

//This will go forward 15 seconds from the start of the video.

Solved